# Mysql 6.1 db error

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am using mysql 6.1 workbench and having issues every time I turn on system. I've tried atleast 50 solutions from different sources but it is not getting fixed. Tried to change default port as well re-installed it quite a few times now. Couldn't understand why it's not getting fixed.

Error is: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061) (2003).

I've seen official documentation in detail and followed each step.

Please help.

Comment: That message implies that the MySQL server isn't running.

Comment: I know but how to start it otherwise if loading workbench isn't working. Just started working with Mysql so would appreciate help.Also checked services.msc as user of Windows no conflict there. For PHP however I can access it via phpmyadmin.

Comment: No idea, this is a system/database administration question, not about programming.

Comment: I figured this out...actually when WAMP and MySQL Workbench both installed only then it shows this issue. Quitting WAMP closes connection so system shuts services down and workbench fails to start service at it's own. By removing one of both won't show such errors. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out...actually when WAMP and MySQL Workbench both installed only then it shows this issue. Quitting WAMP closes connection so system shuts services down and workbench fails to start service at it's own. By removing one of both won't show such errors. Problem solved.